# How to print all the printers with a specific tag

Tags: batch-file

I want to print/and or save all the printer with that specific substring inside it.

```
@echo off
pause
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('wmic printer get name | find /i '\\printR'') do (
    echo %%i
)
pause
```

I try to run it and the cmd windows just disappear

Comment: The command in single quotes is executed by a 2nd cmd.exe, to pass the pipe symbol to it (and not being intercepted by the 1st one) it has to be escaped with a caret `^|` also your single quotes are overlapping, use double quotes with find.

Comment: Tip: Run your script from a `cmd.exe` command window first, and you will get an error. Update your question with the error you get.

Comment: Thank you! the program seems to be working correctly now. Quick question, do you know how to convert the results of the loop into a string? @Bill_Stewart.

Comment: maybe by using `set var=%%i` instead of `echo %%i`?

Answer (score 1):

This first example doesn't use a [for](/questions/tagged/for) loop and should work from a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```bat
@WMIC Printer Where "Name Like '\\\\printR%%'" Get Name|More +1
```

*`More +1` is used above just to remove the header line `Name`, feel free to remove that piping, should that not be required.*

This second example uses a [for](/questions/tagged/for) loop does and is presented below in [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) syntax:

```bat
@For /F "Skip=1Tokens=*" %%A In ('WMIC Printer Where "Name Like '\\\\printR%%'" Get Name 2^>Nul')Do @For /F "Tokens=*" %%B In ("%%A")Do @Echo(%%B
```

*Please note that the latter has not catered for any trailing spaces, so if you were needing it for further use you would need to modify things accordingly, (although the general principal wouldn't change significantly)*.

I have used the `Like` operator with [where](/questions/tagged/where), assuming that your string begins with `\\printR` as per your question. `Like` uses the **`%`** character as a wildcard, so I have used it only at the end of the search string, if you want to match it anywhere in the string use `%%\\\\printR%%` instead. You will also note that the back slash is used as an escape character, so is doubled in order to specify the literal back slashes. You may also be interested to note that the search is not case sensitive, so `\\PRINTr` will also match. The answers above also assume that you are actually wanting to match your `\\printR` string against printer `Name`.

*Please bear in mind that were you to use these examples at the [command-prompt](/questions/tagged/command-prompt) ([cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)), you would modify all instances of **`%%`**, to **`%`**.*